# Всплывающие окна на Xamarin используя Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin

Добрый день. Не могу понять, что не так сделал в использование `Navigation.PushPopupAsync(_InfoPopup);` "Выдает ошибку в `_InfoPopup`: Аргумент 2 не удается преобразовать из `NewsInfoBudgetEntrantBranchBeloretsk` в `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage"`

Использую библиотеку NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/

```
void OnTap(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs position)
{
    var _InfoPopup = new InfoBudgetEntrantBranchBeloretsk();
    Navigation.PushPopupAsync(_InfoPopup); 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Страницы, которые вы хотите показать нужно создавать от класса PopupPage

Comment: Нет, сначала от класса ContentPage, а потом перейти на класс PopupPage

Comment: Минимальным классом в иерархии должен быть `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage` иначе не будет работать

Comment: Есть еще какие-то проблемы по данному вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сделать явное приведение:

var _InfoPopup = (PopupPage) new InfoBudgetEntrantBranchBeloretsk();
Navigation.PushPopupAsync(_InfoPopup);

Comment: Код лучше читается если он отформатирован